# How to replace matching pattern in an array

Tags: bash, scp, array

I have array with name 'arr' which has the following value -

```
post-ro
post-ro-1
post-ro-2
```

I have this variable:

```
str="su scp bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/pg/pri/user.json /etc/bp/pg/pri"
```

I want to run the command defined in the variable `str` by replacing `pg` with the values present in `arr`.
The command present in `str` should be run 3 times (the length of the array) by iterating over the values in `arr` and replacing `pg` in the command with each of them sequentially.

So the final command should be:

```
su scp bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/post-ro/pri/user.json /etc/bp/post-ro/pri
su scp bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/post-ro-1/pri/user.json /etc/bp/post-ro-1/pri
su scp bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/post-ro-2/pri/user.json /etc/bp/post-ro-2/pri
```

Comment: Start with `for pg in "${arr[@]}"; do` and then in the loop replace the string `pg` with the value `"$pg"`

Comment: Also, storing a command in a string has many edge cases. See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Are you _sure_ that is the command you want to run? That will try to execute the command `bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/post-ro/pri/user.json /etc/bp/post-ro/pri` as the user `scp`. I suspect you meant `sudo scp bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/post-ro/pri/user.json /etc/bp/post-ro/pri` and not `su`, but again, there's not much point in running this as root unless it is only root who has the necessary ssh keys to connect to `10.10.10.10` as user `bp`. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you really need to execute

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `xargs`, and assuming that `$str` contains the space separate list of arguments to pass to `su`, you could do:

```
print0() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"
}
IFS=' ' # split on space only
set -o noglob # disable globbing
xargs -r0a <(print0 "${arr[@]}") -I pg -- $str
```

(Leaving `$str` unquoted invokes split+glob, here with glob disabled and split told to split on space only).

If `$str` is to contain the arguments for a `su` command, it would make more sense to use an array:

```
str=(
  su scp bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/pg/pri/user.json /etc/bp/pg/pri
)
xargs -r0a <(print0 "${arr[@]}") -I pg -- "${str[@]}"
```

And then you don't need to fuss with `$IFS` or `noglob` to split that string into arguments.

Comment: Is there any situation where `su scp bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/pg/pri/user.json /etc/bp/pg/pri` can be a valid command? On all the `su` implementations I am familiar with, that will try to run `bp@10.10.10.10:/etc/bp/pg/pri/user.json /etc/bp/pg/pri` as a command, after attempting to switch to user `scp`.

Comment: @terdon, I don't know. `su` is not a standard command. Many systems have a `su` command but with interfaces varying between system. For all we know, the OP's `su` may be a script of his.